# How to get the response from node.js server using ajax.get call

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, mongodb

Below is the code snippet from app.js which returns a aggrgated value from mongo.db. I want to use this  response value in my html page. So, I have written a ajax call. But, the problem is i'm not able to get the value into html page. I can see, that my server is printing the value.

AJAX call made to the server:

```
$(suggestvalue).click(function (e) {
    var datapoint = document.getElementById('criteria').value;
    var criteriaVal = document.getElementById('condi').value;
    var datapoint_val = document.getElementById('rulevalue').value;
    var trigger_action = document.getElementById('actionvalue').value;
    $.ajax({
        url: "/suggestedValueTemp",
        type: 'GET',
        success: function (data) {
            alert("i am here");
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function (e) {
            console.log(e.message);
        }
    });
});

app.get("/suggestedValueTemp",function(req,res){
    mongo.suggestTempValue(function(err,result){
        if(err){
            throw err;
        }else{
            console.log("avgTemp  "+result);
            res.send(result);
        }
    });
});
```

I'm getting this in my console.logs

```
avgTemp  35.17708659524805
[GET /suggestedValueTemp 35.17708659524805 2161ms ]
```

but its not rerouting to success block of my ajax call. Can anybody please help me out.

Thanks,
Shivadeepthi

Comment: Is it firing the error callback? Also, have you tried setting the response code before sending?

Comment: Which `console.log()` statement is producing the console output you show?

Comment: console.log in app.get is giving me those outputs

Comment: What are you seeing in your browser console?

Comment: Nothing. I am not seeing anything on console

Comment: I'd say to look in the network tab of the Chrome or Firefox debugger and see that the desired response is actually coming back to the browser.  If not, the issue is on the server.  If so, set debugger breakpoints in both success and error handlers and see what gets hit.

Comment: Try changing your err check to `if (err) {return res.send(err)};` just to identify where breakdown is happening. If you're using Express (and it looks like you are), add a status code as well - `res.status(500).send(err)`

Comment: I am not having any error, but i am not able to send the data onto html page from app.js

Comment: Did you check the network tab in dev tools per jfriend00's suggestion? If so, what is the response status code?

Comment: Its giving me 304 .Not modified.  And i dont see anything in reponse section.

Comment: Add a 200 status code to your success condition and see if that fixes it.

Comment: You may need to bust cache. Change, "avg temp" to "average temp".

Comment: i added it. how does it impact the response coming from server. In my above console.logs , you can see that success is getting executed and giving me the average value

Comment: It honestly doesn't make sense that you're not seeing anything in the browser console. Either way, success or failure, you should be seeing... something. The discussion is getting lengthy here, but I would suggest adding a simple log statement to success and failure handlers (console.log('success') and console.log('failure')) in order to identify which handler is being fired. If it is the success handler, great. If not, your mongo query is probably erroring out.

Comment: What happens if you type the url into the address on the browser ... i.e. `http://whatever-your-host-is/suggestedValueTemp`

Comment: There's no  /suggestedValueTemp page. I am om /ruleEngine page, where in i have a button called suggest value, on clicking of that button i have to auto populate the field , so for tht i have used ajax call /suggestedTempValue. So, my doubt is should the response be routed to new html page only,cant we get on the page frkm where we sent the request?@Jaromanda X

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your server side code. Change `res.send` to `res.jsonp` and pass an object to it.

```
app.get("/suggestedValueTemp",function(req,res){
    mongo.suggestTempValue(function(err,result){
        if(err){
            throw err;
        }else{
            console.log("avgTemp  "+result);
            res.jsonp({data: result}); //extract the data at user end
        }
    });
});
```